# Can one consume a triboluminescent food-substance on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, science

May one consume a food exhibiting [triboluminescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboluminescence) on Shabbos? Triboluminescence is where light is created from a material being crushed, rubbed, or ripped apart.

When foods are infused with very low concentrations of [Methyl salicylate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methyl_salicylate), they can exhibit triboluminescence, such as [LifeSavers Mints Wint O Green](https://www.thoughtco.com/why-wintergreen-lifesavers-spark-in-the-dark-602179) (which at the time of posting this question are not Kosher). Would chewing foods like this for the purpose of Achila be considered a Melacha (like Mav'ir)? What about chewing it for the purpose of creating light/demonstrating its properties?

In a similar vein, what about rubbing 2 quartz crystals together to produce light?

[image: Life Saver exhibiting triboluminescence.]

Comment: Wouldn’t this be similar to eating a food that has letters?

Comment: @Chatzkel erasing is a bona fide melakha. This is probably nothing

Comment: And yet, even so, the Mishnah berura allows it if you just eat it and it breaks in your mouth. So for sure something like this would be permitted

Comment: @Chatzkel so your comment should be "shouldn't this be no worse than..."

Comment: @double aa I stand corrected.